# Multiple uses of new and delete

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I'm simulating a traditional card game between two players using C++: I defined a "card" structure so that

```
card sample;
cout << sample.numb << " of " << sample.suit << " ownded by player " << sample.own
```

reads e.g. "10 of spades is owned by player 2".

I set up a vector "deck" (of size 40) keeping track of every card, and I'm dynamically allocating vectors "g1" "g2" and "tab" at every step of the game, in order to handle player 1's hand, player 2's hand and cards on the table with three separated objects (this is kind of necessary for the game itself).

Since the players keep putting cards on the table and gaining/losing new cards the sizes keep changing, so every time I do something like this:

```
delete g1;
delete g2;
delete tab;
n1=count (1,deck);  // this counts how many cards in "deck" have .own field==1
n2=count (2,deck);  // this counts how many cards in "deck" have .own field==2
nt=count (0,deck);  // cards having .own field == 0 are on the table
g1 = new card [n1];
g2 = new card [n2];
tab = new card [nt];
k=0;               // using this to move through the vectors I just re-allocated
for (i=0;i<40;i++) {
  if(deck[i].own==1) {
     g1[k]=deck[i];
     k++;
  }
}
// then I fill "g2" and "tab" pretty much in the same way
```

The script compiles and runs, but after a couple of rounds (carried out correctly) I get "invalid next size (fast)" and a segfault.
Reading around I found out that this usually happens when you try to delete something twice or the likes of it.
My script doesn't delete anything twice, but I suspect that such a frequent use of new-delete-new is deprecated and might be the cause of my problem.

Thoughts?

EDIT I solved my issue using std::vector, I suggest doing the same to anyone ever having the same problem; thanks to everyone who answered.

Peace,

Tom

Comment: The error might occur on ur 'count(int, deck)'.

Comment: @vadz it's a really simple function, like
n=0;
for (i=0;i<40;i++) if(deck[i].own==p) n++;
with p being the int given to the function when called

Comment: The only problems in the code you've posted are the wrong deletion style (see answer), and the error-prone usage of raw pointers. Possible problems in the code you didn't post: you might not be setting `k` back to zero before each loop; you might be comparing `own` with the wrong values in the other loops; you might not be initialising the pointers to null before the first deletions.

Comment: Where do u set "deck[i].own =1;" ?

Comment: @MikeSeymour checked the points you suggested and set the pointers to null but it didn't change much, my bad memory handling seems to be the point here..

Comment: I believe the value of the card is called the "rank", if you really want to use four letters.

Comment: @vadz there's a 'shuffle' function I call in the very beginning, assigning either 1 or 2 to .own field of every position of deck[ ]; the function itself works correctly (I'm cout-ing each player's hand at every step of the game).
As the game proceeds the .own fields is modified whenever the card is placed on the table (.own=0) or a player gets it into his hand.

Comment: @Potatoswatter my code uses shorter "tags" in a foreign language, I made em rather long and english to make it easier for you :p

Comment: You should check your assumption at the end of the loop: that is, verify that `k == count(..., deck);` where `...` is 0, 1 or 2 accordingly. My spidey sense is telling me that you'll find that's not always the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better use array deletion for g1, g2 and tab:
eg: delete [] g1;

Of course, you're far better off using std::vector and not handling the memory management directly yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I tried array deletion as you suggested but didn't solve much.
I'll try to look into std::vector documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If the deck has 40 cards, then no player can have more than 40 cards and the table can't have more than 40 cards. Just create arrays of 40 cards. Dynamic allocation is overkill here.

Comment: Ahh, the voice of reason! Bu... bu... but what if you have four players?!? ;)

Comment: @NikBougalis - doesn't change the underlying analysis. Each hand is an array of up to 40 cards; that's small enough that there's no point in going through all the wheel-spinning involved in reallocating the array to exactly fit the current number of cards.

Comment: Uhm... I was being sarcastic Pete.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah you're right, but I wanted to take this chance for learning some dynamic allocation anyway, so I tried writing something overly elegant (wich ended up being overly ugly, duh).